# Why isn't getJSON returning the API respone?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to store API return into a `var`, but it´s returning `undefined` when trying to log it to console, it seems to be empty.

This is the code

```
    fetchMovies: function(city) {
        var myjson;
        $.getJSON('api/city?city=' + city, function(json) {
            // console.debug(json);
            myjson = json;
        });
        console.log(myjson); //
        this.filmer.push(this.myjson); // Push results to div?
}
```

`console.debug(json)` returns:

```
data: {91: "Nothing", 92: "Mr robot"}
name: "Stockholm"
```

End when access by browser the return looks like:

```
{
"name": "Stockholm",
"data": {
"91": "Nothing",
"92": "Mr Robot"
}
}
```

And the API request is
http://localhost:8000/api/city?city=Stockholm

How do i store the JSON response?

Comment: Because `getJSON` is an async call - and `myjson` hasn't gotten the response yet. Move your `push` into the callback (and then `this` won't be the same context either)

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)